# t:selectOneMenu how to get selected value using java script?

Tags: javascript, jsf

i want to get the select one menu using java script **how can i get the selecteditem**  value?

```
<h:outputLabel value="#{l.description1}" styleClass="dataValue" />
<t:selectOneMenu id="chooseLevelTypeId"
    value="#{AssetWizardComptTypeTile.levelTypeId}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="0" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{GeneralTables.levelTypesList}" />
    <a4j:support event="onchange" action="#{WizardMainControl.action}"
        ??oncomplete="if (document.getElementById('wizardForm:chooseLevelTypeId').selecteditem == 'somthing') 
        document.getElementById('wizardForm:a1').style.display = 'block';"
        reRender="chooseLevelTypeDesc" />
</t:selectOneMenu>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

now get selectone menu item using javascript as

```
var selectedValue = document.getElementById("wizardForm:chooseLevelTypeId").value;
```

here selectedValue is your selected item.

Comment: +1 thx for the help. I've been trying `getElementById("#wizardForm:chooseLevelTypeId")` for a long time until i came across this answer. Why is that you can leave the `#` out in jsf, but anywhere else you need the `#` to specifiy an `id`?