# Open a dialog box in same window on selectOneMenu change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2, jquery-selectors, primefaces

I have a jsf page where I have a selectOneMenu and , I want to open a dialog box on selectOneMenu changes.

> As a example if user selects a value ="passive"  from jsf selectOneMenu it
>   should open a dialog box or a light box on same page where I want to
>   display a small jsf form  like as here done.(please click on that small image(yes, like this dialog box I want to open after selecting particular 
>   value in selectOneMenu)
>   )
>   http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/dialogLogin.jsf

and I also want save that submitted data in my backing bean somewhere so I can store it in to database later.

I dont know how to open a dialog box or light box from backing bean in same window,as we will identify value change using valueChangeListener event or by using ajax event.

I am able to identify which value is selected from selectOneMenu(DropdownMenu), but dont know how to open a dialog box on selecting particular value.

```
<h:outputLabel
            value="* Country: "/>
        <h:selectOneMenu
            id="someSelect"
            value="#{testController.countryName}"
            required="true">
            <f:selectItem
                itemLabel="Select Country"
                itemValue=""/>
            <f:selectItems
                value="#{testController.countryNamesSelectItems}"/>
             </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Supoose we have 2 options in selectItems as India and Austrlia, then If a user choose India 
a dialog box should open on same page where a user need to fill some information and need to submit 
if he is from india (like here in example  http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/dialogLogin.jsf (please click on that small image(yes, like this dialog box I want to open after selecting particular 
value in selectOneMenu)
)user will put his username and password and submits data)

Hope this helps

> how can we check in primefaces , selected value of selectOneMenu using
>   java script(jquery) like done here for richfaces
>   [t:selectOneMenu how to get selected value using java script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482959/tselectonemenu-how-to-get-selected-value-using-java-script)?

Comment: let me know if anybody needs more clarification

Comment: @Matt has shown me a good way.Now At this stage, I am not able to get selected value of selectOneMenu, How can I get that in primefaces? –

Comment: Ok, let's try again: What is the id of the generated `<select>` in the html source? Find the id and then add the full id with escaped colons in your jQuery call, for example: `$('#myform\\:selectedGroupId').val()`

Comment: Hey Matt,I am able to display dialog box using this.
if($("select[name$='someSelect_input'] option:selected").val() == 'India') { 
 dlg.show(); 

}

& Thanks for perfect guidence... it really helped me

Comment: Good to hear that it works. I still wonder why the id selector didn't work ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `onchange` attribute of `h:selectOneMenu` to open the dialog:

```
 <h:selectOneMenu
        id="someSelect"
        value="#{testController.countryName}"
        required="true"
        onchange="dlg.show()">
```

With `dlg` as value of the `widgetVar` attribute of the `p:dialog`. This will open the dialog *before* the server is hit.

If you want to open the dialog *after* completion of an ajax request you can use `p:ajax` with the `oncomplete` attribute:

```
<p:ajax update=".." process=".." oncomplete="dlg.show()"/>
```

Or if you want to make opening the dialog dependent on the selected value you could use a wrapper function:

```
function showDialog() {
 if($('#IdOfYourSelectOneMenu').val() == 'India') {
   dlg.show();
 }
}
```

with:

```
<p:ajax update=".." process=".." oncomplete="showDialog()"/>
```

Comment: ok, but if i will use onchange then on any dropdownmenu selection i will get that dialog box open, but i need to open it only on particular value is get selected. then how wht should I need to do?

Comment: If you want to do it on client side only, you could write a javascript wrapper function for `dlg.show()` that first checks the selected value and then opens the dialog. Or register your own javascript/jQuery eventlistener.

Comment: yes exactly, but how can I do in javascript, that if particular value is selected open Dialog box.?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12103/discussion-between-pravingate-and-matt-handy)